# Stopwatch changing button text in c#

Tags: c#, arrays, multithreading, timer, stopwatch

Basically, I've got multiple button in my Form, and I want for it show a Stopwatch in the button.Text when the button is pressed. (Button is modified to be a toggle button.) and to stop and reset the timmer when the button is toggled off. Simple enough it seemed but because I have multiple buttons that could be pressed in any order, and I don't know anything about threading, this seems to be much more difficult that I presumed.

My origional intent was to have a function that constantly runs every second and interates a interager only if the button is pressed using this code:

```
public void Jogger()//purpose is to step up time[0] every second only when a button is on.
    {
        while (true)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++)
            {
                if (btnstat[i])
                    time[i]++;
            }
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
    }
```

Problem is, I don't know threading so when I call the function, its stuck doing this and only this.

Either way, once this is called, all i do us call my update function that updates all the buttons including the button.Text which displays the time[0]; (array built around buttons)

Is their a better way of doing this that doesn't cause so much CPU use and/or simply works?

Thanks for all the help!
-John Ivey

Comment: I don't quite understand what you are trying to do. Do you have (or want) one or multiple timers? And do you want to start/stop the stopwatch when a click happens on any button or just a specific button?

Comment: You are sleeping the main thread causing your UI to freeze.

Comment: I have mutliple buttons, each controlling a timer of their own. And the start and stop of their respective timers, are controlled by the buttons themselves. So when button1 is on, the timer starts and displays on button1.Text. and stops button1 is off. it has to be able to do this at the same time as any other. So button1 and button5 could be on and running their own timmers. Understand?

Comment: Your "Button" should either **Derive** from Button or be a **UserControl** so all that functionality is **Encapsulated** within itself.  This will allow all of them run independently of each other and not depend on the forms code to operate.  Also, you should use the **Stopwatch** class and a simple Timer() to update the **Elapsed()** property into the Text of the Button.

Comment: @JohnIvey check my post. tested too . think it does what u want . and u can attach as many buttons as you want .

Answer (score 0):

`Application.DoEvents()` for simplicity put inside loop .  . but it is advisable to start to lean `threading` . you will just learn how to start thread and how make cross thread safe call
Next simple will be to use `backgroundworker` . look this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx

*ok here is thread solution also as you wanted . Tested too . as a stop variable i used Tag. But u can inherit button to make state button.it be more clear way . **And below code will use one thread per button . So u should make it in one thread to make it better solution** . You can modify this code to do all checkings inside one thread . For this you  start thread once can make delegate for attaching dinamically count function for each button or you can pass buttons before . With one word there are more than one way to do it. Good luck*

```
this.button1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button_Click);
this.button2.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button_Click);
...and so on
  private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           Thread x= new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(Jogger2));
            x.Start(sender);

        }


        private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button mybtn=sender as Button;
        if((string)mybtn.Tag=="start"){
            mybtn.Tag ="";
            return;
         }
        mybtn.Tag = "start";
       Thread x= new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(Jogger2));
        x.Start(sender);

    }


    private bool  setResult(object obj,string text)
    { 
        if (this.textBox1.InvokeRequired)
        {
            Func<Button,string, bool > d = new Func<Button,string,bool >(setResult);
            return (bool)this.Invoke(d,obj,text);

        }
        else
        {
            Button btn=obj  as Button;

            if (btn != null)
            {
                btn.Text = text;
                if ((string)btn.Tag !="start") return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
    private void Jogger2(object mybtn)
    {
        int ii = 0; 
        while (true)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
                //replace with your code
                ii += 1;
                if (!setResult(mybtn, ii.ToString())) break; 

        }

    }
```

Comment: I'm confused on how Application.DoEvents() is suppose to help?

Comment: @JohnIvey inside your loop

Comment: I put it inside the while(true) statement, still 'hangs'. :\

Comment: Instead of sleep use time . wait i will post you solution with thread and with application doevents

Comment: I see what your talking about. My other issue is that I have (16) multiple buttons. Each with a different name. Each having to have a different time all seperated from each other. :\

Comment: @JohnIvey ok then use backgroundworker or threads . when you are getting result .after completing ?

Comment: ok, thanks! I'll look that up. still in very basic programming. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @JohnIvey check my post. tested too . think it does what u want . and u can attach as many buttons as you want .

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you using checkbox with property Button = Appearence, in event handler for CheckedChanged:

```
private void CheckBoxCheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) sender;

    if (checkBox.Checked)
    {
        Timer timer = new Timer {Interval = 1000};
        timer.Tick += Jogger;
        timer.Start();
        timer.Tag = new CheckboxCounter {CheckBox = checkBox, Time = 0};
        checkBox.Tag = timer;
    }
    else
    {
        Timer timer = checkBox.Tag as Timer;
        if (timer != null)
        {
            timer.Tag = null;
            timer.Stop();
            timer.Dispose();
            checkBox.Tag = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Change your Jogger function:

```
private void Jogger(object a_sender, EventArgs a_eventArgs)
{
    Timer timer = (Timer) a_sender;
    CheckboxCounter data = (CheckboxCounter)timer.Tag;
    data.Time++;
    data.CheckBox.Text = data.Time.ToString();
}
```

You also need some simple class to store checkbox and current time:

```
class CheckboxCounter
{
    public CheckBox CheckBox;

    public int Time;
}
```

Then you can add any number of checkboxes and just set event CheckedChanged to CheckBoxCheckedChanged.

Comment: I really want the String of the time to be in the button. (ie Button1.Text) or do I simply missunderstand your code?

Answer (score 0):

Try this out.  After re-building or running, you should have the new "ButtonTimer" at the top of your ToolBox.  Drop a couple on your Form, run it, and see what happens when you click them.  Right click them to "Reset" them:

```
public class ButtonTimer : CheckBox
{

    private System.Windows.Forms.Timer Tmr = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
    private System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch SW = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();

    public ButtonTimer()
    {
        this.Tmr.Interval = 500;
        this.Tmr.Tick += new EventHandler(tmr_Tick);
        this.Appearance = System.Windows.Forms.Appearance.Button;
        this.CheckedChanged += new EventHandler(ButtonTimer_CheckedChanged);

        ContextMenuStrip cms = new ContextMenuStrip();
        ToolStripItem tsi = cms.Items.Add("Reset");
        tsi.Click += new EventHandler(tsi_Click);
        this.ContextMenuStrip = cms;
    }

    protected override void OnLayout(LayoutEventArgs levent)
    {
        base.OnLayout(levent);
        this.Text = TimeSpan.Zero.ToString(@"hh\:mm\:ss");
    }

    private void ButtonTimer_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.Checked)
        {
            this.SW.Start();
            this.Tmr.Start();
        }
        else
        {
            this.SW.Stop();
            this.Tmr.Stop();
        }
    }

    private void tmr_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.UpdateTime();
    }

    private void UpdateTime()
    {
        this.Text = this.SW.Elapsed.ToString(@"hh\:mm\:ss");
    }

    private void tsi_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.SW.IsRunning)
        {
            SW.Restart();
        }
        else
        {
            SW.Reset();
        }
        this.UpdateTime();
    }

}
```