# Multiple simultaneous stopwatches in c#

Tags: c#, multithreading, button, toggle, timing

I've got 16 different toggle buttons. They need to toggle a stop watch. When button is on, stop watch starts, when button turned off, stop watch stops and resets. This gets complicated when there 16 buttons, and each has to control their individual stopwatchs. At any time the user could turn on all or some of the buttons turning on their respective stopwatchs. Any clues on how to achieve this? I'm trying threading but that doesn't seem to work without running into cross thread communication. Any ideas? I can post the code i have if you want it but its the concepts that matter.

Hell, just in case, heres the code:

```
public partial class Main : Form
{
    //declares global varaibles for easy use accross functions
    bool[] btnstat = new bool[16];
    int UnitNumber = 0, LineNumber = 0;
    String IPaddress = "", message = "";
    bool[] X = new bool[17];
    String[] Y = new String[17];
    bool[] Z = new bool[17];
    double[] time = new double[16];
    bool run = false;
    String serial = Generator.GetMotherBoardID();

    public Main()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }//end Main()

    private void Main_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {            
        //checks for initial setup
        System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader("Welcome.config");
        string x = file.ReadLine();
        file.Close();
        if (!String.Equals(x, "1px7ngme9dny"))
        {
            Welcome M = new Welcome();
            M.ShowDialog();//pauses program until Welcome page has been closed
        }
        //Console.WriteLine("Serieal : " + serial);//For making sure the serial is pulled correctly

        //Resets all buttons to disabled, invisible, and hidden off page.
        Btn1.Enabled = false; Btn1.Visible = false; Btn1.Top = -30;
        btn2.Enabled = false; btn2.Visible = false; btn2.Top = -30;
        btn3.Enabled = false; btn3.Visible = false; btn3.Top = -30;
        btn4.Enabled = false; btn4.Visible = false; btn4.Top = -30;
        btn5.Enabled = false; btn5.Visible = false; btn5.Top = -30;
        btn6.Enabled = false; btn6.Visible = false; btn6.Top = -30;
        btn7.Enabled = false; btn7.Visible = false; btn7.Top = -30;
        btn8.Enabled = false; btn8.Visible = false; btn8.Top = -30;
        btn9.Enabled = false; btn9.Visible = false; btn9.Top = -30;
        btn10.Enabled = false; btn10.Visible = false; btn10.Top = -30;
        btn11.Enabled = false; btn11.Visible = false; btn11.Top = -30;
        btn12.Enabled = false; btn12.Visible = false; btn12.Top = -30;
        btn13.Enabled = false; btn13.Visible = false; btn13.Top = -30;
        btn14.Enabled = false; btn14.Visible = false; btn14.Top = -30;
        btn15.Enabled = false; btn15.Visible = false; btn15.Top = -30;
        btn16.Enabled = false; btn16.Visible = false; btn16.Top = -30;

        FileReader();
        Updater(); //calls updater to update the program with configuration and calculations
    }//end Main_Load
    public void plusplus()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++)
        {
            if (btnstat[i])
                time[i]++;
            else
                time[i] = 0;
        }
        Updater();
    }

    public void FileReader()
    {
        //declaration
        System.IO.StreamReader file2 = new System.IO.StreamReader("ConfigurationSettings.config");

        //loads all saved data into memory
        for (int i = 1; i <= 53; i++)
        {
            if (i == 1)
            {
                if (String.Equals(file2.ReadLine(), "Yes"))
                {
                }
            }
            else if (i == 2)
            {
                String z = file2.ReadLine();
                if (!String.Equals(null, z))
                    CompName.Text = z;
                else
                    CompName.Text = "Company Name";
            }
            else if (i == 3)
            {
                String z = file2.ReadLine();
                if (!String.Equals(null, z))
                    CompLoc.Text = z;
                else
                    CompLoc.Text = "Company Location";
            }
            else if (i == 4)
            {
                String z = file2.ReadLine();
                if (!String.Equals(null, z))
                {
                    LineNum.Text = "Line: " + z; LineNumber = Convert.ToInt32(z);
                }
                else
                    LineNum.Text = "Line Number: ";
            }
            else if (i == 5)
            {
                String z = file2.ReadLine();
                if (!String.Equals(null, z))
                {
                    UnitNum.Text = "Unit: " + z; UnitNumber = Convert.ToInt32(z);
                }
                else
                    UnitNum.Text = "Unit Number: ";
            }
            else if ((i >= 6) && (i <= 21))
                X[i - 6] = Convert.ToBoolean(file2.ReadLine());
            else if ((i >= 22) && (i <= 37))
                Y[i - 22] = file2.ReadLine();
            else if ((i >= 38) && (i <= 53))
                Z[i - 38] = Convert.ToBoolean(file2.ReadLine());
        }
        IPaddress = file2.ReadLine();
        file2.Close();
    }
    public void Updater()//This reloads everything. From status to what buttons are enabled.
    {
        //Sets all buttons again
        int j = 0;
        if (X[0])
        {
            Btn1.Enabled = true; Btn1.Visible = true; Btn1.Top = (80 + j); Btn1.Text = Y[0]; j += 46;
        }
        if (X[1])
        {
            btn2.Enabled = true; btn2.Visible = true; btn2.Top = (80 + j); btn2.Text = Y[1]; j += 46;
        }
        if (X[2])
        {
            btn3.Enabled = true; btn3.Visible = true; btn3.Top = (80 + j); btn3.Text = Y[2]; j += 46;
        }
        if (X[3])
        {
            btn4.Enabled = true; btn4.Visible = true; btn4.Top = (80 + j); btn4.Text = Y[3]; j += 46;
        }
        if (X[4])
        {
            btn5.Enabled = true; btn5.Visible = true; btn5.Top = (80 + j); btn5.Text = Y[4]; j += 46;
        }
        if (X[5])
        {
            btn6.Enabled = true; btn6.Visible = true; btn6.Top = (80 + j); btn6.Text = Y[5]; j += 46;
        }
        if (X[6])
        {
            btn7.Enabled = true; btn7.Visible = true; btn7.Top = (80 + j); btn7.Text = Y[6]; j += 46;
        }
        if (X[7])
        {
            btn8.Enabled = true; btn8.Visible = true; btn8.Top = (80 + j); btn8.Text = Y[7]; j += 46;
        }
        if (X[8])
        {
            btn9.Enabled = true; btn9.Visible = true; btn9.Top = (80 + j); btn9.Text = Y[8]; j += 46;
        }
        if (X[9])
        {
            btn10.Enabled = true; btn10.Visible = true; btn10.Top = (80 + j); btn10.Text = Y[9]; j += 46;
        }
        if (X[10])
        {
            btn11.Enabled = true; btn11.Visible = true; btn11.Top = (80 + j); btn11.Text = Y[10]; j += 46;
        }
        if (X[11])
        {
            btn12.Enabled = true; btn12.Visible = true; btn12.Top = (80 + j); btn12.Text = Y[11]; j += 46;
        }
        if (X[12])
        {
            btn13.Enabled = true; btn13.Visible = true; btn13.Top = (80 + j); btn13.Text = Y[12]; j += 46;
        }
        if (X[13])
        {
            btn14.Enabled = true; btn14.Visible = true; btn14.Top = (80 + j); btn14.Text = Y[13]; j += 46;
        }
        if (X[14])
        {
            btn15.Enabled = true; btn15.Visible = true; btn15.Top = (80 + j); btn15.Text = Y[14]; j += 46;
        }
        if (X[15])
        {
            btn16.Enabled = true; btn16.Visible = true; btn16.Top = (80 + j); btn16.Text = Y[15]; j += 46;
        }
        this.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(175, (120 + j));

        //sets correct 'On if all others are off'
        bool allareoff = true;
        for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++)
        {
            if (btnstat[i] == true && Z[i] == false)
                allareoff = false;
        }
        if (allareoff)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++)
            {
                if (Z[i] == true)
                    btnstat[i] = true;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++)
            {
                if (Z[i] == true)
                    btnstat[i] = false;
            }
        }

        //updates buttons to current status
        if (btnstat[0])
        {
            Btn1.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat; Btn1.Image = ((System.Drawing.Image)(Properties.Resources.Rl)); Btn1.Text = Y[0] + "\r\n" + time[0];
        }
        else
        {
            Btn1.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Popup; Btn1.Image = ((System.Drawing.Image)(Properties.Resources.Rd));Btn1.Text = Y[0];time[0] = 0;
        }
        if (btnstat[1])
        {
            btn2.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat; btn2.Image = ((System.Drawing.Image)(Properties.Resources.Rl)); btn2.Text = Y[1] + "\r\n" + time[1];
        }
        else
        {
            btn2.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Popup; btn2.Image = ((System.Drawing.Image)(Properties.Resources.Rd));btn2.Text = Y[1];time[1] = 0;
        }
        if (btnstat[2])
        {
            btn3.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat; btn3.Image = ((System.Drawing.Image)(Properties.Resources.Yl)); btn3.Text = Y[2] + "\r\n" + time[2];
        }
        else
        {
            btn3.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Popup; btn3.Image = ((System.Drawing.Image)(Properties.Resources.Yd));btn3.Text = Y[2];time[2] = 0;
        }
        if (btnstat[3])
        {
            btn4.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat; btn4.Image = ((System.Drawing.Image)(Properties.Resources.Yl)); btn4.Text = Y[3] + "\r\n" + time[3];
        }
        else
        {
            btn4.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Popup; btn4.Image = ((System.Drawing.Image)(Properties.Resources.Yd));btn4.Text = Y[3];time[3] = 0;
        }
        if (btnstat[4])
        {
            btn5.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat; btn5.Image = ((System.Drawing.Image)(Properties.Resources.Gl)); btn5.Text = Y[4] + "\r\n" + time[4];
        }
        else
        {
            btn5.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Popup; btn5.Image = ((System.Drawing.Image)(Properties.Resources.Gd));btn5.Text = Y[4];time[4] = 0;
        }
        if (btnstat[5])
        {
            btn6.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat; btn6.Image = ((System.Drawing.Image)(Properties.Resources.Gl)); btn6.Text = Y[5] + "\r\n" + time[5];
        }
        else
        {
            btn6.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Popup; btn6.Image = ((System.Drawing.Image)(Properties.Resources.Gd));btn6.Text = Y[5];time[5] = 0;
        }
        if (btnstat[6])
        {
            btn7.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat; btn7.Image = ((System.Drawing.Image)(Properties.Resources.Bl)); btn7.Text = Y[6] + "\r\n" + time[6];
        }
        else
        {
            btn7.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Popup; btn7.Image = ((System.Drawing.Image)(Properties.Resources.Bd));btn7.Text = Y[6];time[6] = 0;
        }
        if (btnstat[7])
        {
            btn8.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat; btn8.Image = ((System.Drawing.Image)(Properties.Resources.Bl)); btn8.Text = Y[7] + "\r\n" + time[7];
        }
        else
        {
            btn8.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Popup; btn8.Image = ((System.Drawing.Image)(Properties.Resources.Bd));btn8.Text = Y[7];time[7] = 0;
        }
        if (btnstat[8])
        {
            btn9.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat; btn9.Image = ((System.Drawing.Image)(Properties.Resources.Wl)); btn9.Text = Y[8] + "\r\n" + time[8];
        }
        else
        {
            btn9.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Popup; btn9.Image = ((System.Drawing.Image)(Properties.Resources.Wd)); btn9.Text = Y[8]; time[8] = 0;
        }
        if (btnstat[9])
        {
            btn10.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat; btn10.Image = ((System.Drawing.Image)(Properties.Resources.Wl)); btn10.Text = Y[9] + "\r\n" + time[9];
        }
        else
        {
            btn10.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Popup; btn10.Image = ((System.Drawing.Image)(Properties.Resources.Wd)); btn10.Text = Y[9]; time[9] = 0;
        }
        if (btnstat[10])
        {
            btn11.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat; btn11.Image = ((System.Drawing.Image)(Properties.Resources.Wl)); btn11.Text = Y[10] + "\r\n" + time[10];
        }
        else
        {
            btn11.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Popup; btn11.Image = ((System.Drawing.Image)(Properties.Resources.Wd)); btn11.Text = Y[10]; time[10] = 0;
        }
        if (btnstat[11])
        {
            btn12.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat; btn12.Image = ((System.Drawing.Image)(Properties.Resources.Wl)); btn12.Text = Y[11] + "\r\n" + time[11];
        }
        else
        {
            btn12.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Popup; btn12.Image = ((System.Drawing.Image)(Properties.Resources.Wd)); btn12.Text = Y[11]; time[11] = 0;
        }
        if (btnstat[12])
        {
            btn13.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat; btn13.Image = ((System.Drawing.Image)(Properties.Resources.Wl)); btn13.Text = Y[12] + "\r\n" + time[12];
        }
        else
        {
            btn13.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Popup; btn13.Image = ((System.Drawing.Image)(Properties.Resources.Wd)); btn13.Text = Y[12]; time[12] = 0;
        }
        if (btnstat[13])
        {
            btn14.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat; btn14.Image = ((System.Drawing.Image)(Properties.Resources.Wl)); btn14.Text = Y[13] + "\r\n" + time[13];
        }
        else
        {
            btn14.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Popup; btn14.Image = ((System.Drawing.Image)(Properties.Resources.Wd)); btn14.Text = Y[13]; time[13] = 0;
        }
        if (btnstat[14])
        {
            btn15.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat; btn15.Image = ((System.Drawing.Image)(Properties.Resources.Wl));btn15.Text = Y[14] + "\r\n" + time[14];
        }
        else
        {
            btn15.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Popup; btn15.Image = ((System.Drawing.Image)(Properties.Resources.Wd)); btn15.Text = Y[14]; time[14] = 0;
        }
        if (btnstat[15])
        {
            btn16.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat; btn16.Image = ((System.Drawing.Image)(Properties.Resources.Wl));btn16.Text = Y[15] + "\r\n" + time[15];
        }
        else
        {
            btn16.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Popup; btn16.Image = ((System.Drawing.Image)(Properties.Resources.Wl)); btn16.Text = Y[15]; time[15] = 0;
        } 
        //sends all the data;
        String[] intA = new String[16];
        String ln,un = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++)
        {
            if (btnstat[i] == true)
                intA[i] = "0";
            else
                intA[i] = "1";
        }
        if (LineNumber < 10)
            ln = "0" + LineNumber;
        else
            ln = Convert.ToString(LineNumber);
        if (UnitNumber < 10)
            un = "0" + UnitNumber;
        else
            un = Convert.ToString(UnitNumber);
        //creates the string to send.
        message ="" + ln + " " + un + " " +intA[7]+intA[6]+intA[5]+intA[4]+intA[3]+intA[2]+intA[1]+intA[0]+" "+intA[15]+intA[14]+intA[13]+intA[12]+intA[11]+intA[10]+intA[9]+intA[8]+" "+serial;
        IPLabel.Text = "IP: " + IPaddress;
    }//end updater

    public void Sender()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(IPaddress + ": " + message);//for referancing
        Send(IPaddress, 8000, message);//sends message
    }

    public void Send(string server, int port, string message)
    {
        try
        {
            // Create a TcpClient.
            TcpClient client = new TcpClient(server, port);

            // Translate
            Byte[] data = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(message);

            // Get a client stream
            NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();

            // Send the message
            stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);

            // Close 
            stream.Close();
            client.Close();
        }
        catch (ArgumentNullException e)
        {
            // trap error
        }
        catch (SocketException e)
        {
            // trap error
        }
    }  //end send
    private void IALogo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Config config = new Config();
        config.ShowDialog(); // code here STOPS until "config" is closed
        FileReader();
        Updater();
    }
    private void Main_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        Application.Exit();
    }

    private void toolTip1_Popup(object sender, PopupEventArgs e){}

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){}

    private void CompLoc_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){}

    private void menuStrip1_ItemClicked(object sender, ToolStripItemClickedEventArgs e){}

    private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        btnstat[5] = !btnstat[5];
        var stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
        if(btnstat[4])
        {
        stopwatch.Start();
        time[4] = stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds / 1000;
        }
        else
        {
            stopwatch.Stop();
            time[4] = 0;
        }
        Updater();
        Sender();
    }

    private void Btn1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        btnstat[0] = !btnstat[0];
        Updater();
        Sender();
    }

    private void btn2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        btnstat[1] = !btnstat[1];
        Updater();
        Sender();
    }

    private void btn3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        btnstat[2] = !btnstat[2];
        Updater();
        Sender();
    }

    private void btn4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        btnstat[3] = !btnstat[3];
        Updater();
        Sender();
    }

    private void btn5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        btnstat[4] = !btnstat[4];
        Updater();
        Sender();
    }

    private void btn7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        btnstat[6] = !btnstat[6];
        Updater();
        Sender();
    }

    private void btn8_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        btnstat[7] = !btnstat[7];
        Updater();
        Sender();
    }

    private void btn9_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        btnstat[8] = !btnstat[8];
        Updater();
        Sender();
    }

    private void btn10_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        btnstat[9] = !btnstat[9];
        Updater();
        Sender();
    }

    private void btn11_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        btnstat[10] = !btnstat[10];
        Updater();
        Sender();
    }

    private void btn12_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        btnstat[11] = !btnstat[11];
        Updater();
        Sender();
    }

    private void btn13_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        btnstat[12] = !btnstat[12];
        Updater();
        Sender();
    }

    private void btn14_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        btnstat[13] = !btnstat[13];
        Updater();
        Sender();
    }

    private void btn15_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        btnstat[14] = !btnstat[14];
        Updater();
        Sender();
    }

    private void btn16_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        btnstat[15] = !btnstat[15];
        Updater();
        Sender();
    }
```

Thanks for all the help!

Comment: Are we talking about `System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch`s ?  If so, they simply record the timestamp when started/stopped to calculate elapsed time. They're not actually *doing* anything when they're running.

Comment: for your first question, yes I am using System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch. As for your second comment, as you are right, the problem is I want each of the text labels associated with the buttons to display the stopwatch time every half second or so. I don't know how to refresh those every half second without hogging the thread.

Comment: Also, err.. in 99% of all GUIs, it's fairly easy to iterate through all components in an array, so there is no need for 16 lines of code that are almost the same.  Also, no need for 16 Click handlers - you know what 'object sender' is, right?

Comment: Yeah, I wasn't aware that you could name the GUI's in an array (btn[0],btn[1],btn[2]) I am an amerature and it shows. [cant even spell] and no I don't.

Comment: You want to use a single `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` to update all of the `Label`s at a pre-defined interval.  No threading necessary, as it uses the standard Win32 message loop.

Comment: Did you try my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16678808/2330053) in your last question about this?  Try it with a new Form to see how it works...

Comment: @JohnIvey A couple things: 1) This isn't a "Forum" we don't mark threads as "[SOLVED]". Instead, answers are marked as accepted.  Which leads me to point 2) You should accept an answer (on your other) question if it solves your problem, and don't please ask the same question multiple times.